Does Oracle WebLogic WLS 14c support Java 17?
Wikipedia says Weblogic latest version only supports Java 11.
But why does this prevent me from installing Java 17 (or even Java 21)?
Is it not the case, that Java is downward compatible?
Can anyone tell a concrete example where using Java 17 in Weblogic 14c would cause a problem.

Most things are compatible, but a few things that once worked are no longer allowed. A common issue is using reflection to access the internals of standard classes which is now forbidden. I don't know if that applies to Weblogic.

Instead of wikipedia I would recommend to read the requirements from the documentation of the product. A Java application server is a complex beast and it is expected to stick to the documented requirements. Also note that instead of asking for other people examples of problems you should be describing your own problem. Why you can not use Java 11 as expected?

I am not using WebLogic at the moment. But I could start working in a project which uses this technology. And of course it is an impediment not being able to use the latest Java features. And Java always proclaims to be downward compatible.
